# How to check possible all combinations of elements in an array that fullfil certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, combinatorics

I am currently writing (as an exercise) a simple political calculator that checks depending on how many seats each party has, possible majorities in the parliament.

I have created an object that holds the name as **key** and the seats as **value**, like so:

```
let testData = {
        "party1":19,
        "party2":29,
        "party3":10,
     }
```

I then use Object(entries) to move the data into an array:

```
let testArr = Object.entries(testData);
```

My question is, how can I check what possible combinations there are to get more than 30(seats) without duplication ?

From the above example, none of the parties get alone over 30, so some combinations are needed.

For example - party1 + party2 = 48 this is more than 30 so I save that result.
But I wish to avoid having the result party2 + party1 = 48, because the order of the parties is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to prettiest but does the job, runs over the entries and then again to check them against each other. If the sum is over the threshold it will add them to the result with corresponding key.

```js
let testData = {
  party1: 19,
  party2: 29,
  party3: 10,
};

const combinations = new Set();
const threshold = 30;

const result = {};

Object.entries(testData).map(([key1, value1]) => {
  return Object.entries(testData).map(([key2, value2]) => {
    if (key1 === key2) return; // party1 === party1 do nothing

    // take care of the doubles, party1 + party2 === party2 + party1
    const key = [key1, key2].sort().join(":");
    if (combinations.has(key)) return;
    combinations.add(key);

    // check if the sum is over the threshold
    const sum = value1 + value2;
    if (sum > threshold) result[key] = sum;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works flawlessly. Could you elaborate a bit how exactly the code that compares if party1===party1 and if party1+2===party2+1 works ? 

I was trying nested for loops but my actual calculator has 8 parties and it become overwhelming with that many nested loops. It also wasn't working at all.

Comment: `key1` and `key2` both represent "party1" for the first iteration. They are equal so do nothing/return. Second iteration of the inner loop `key2` represents "party2" so not equal. To take care of party1+2 === party2+1 I place them in an array sort them so we always have the same array and then join them to make a string. For 8 parties this approach could get quite big.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use nested loop where outerloop handles keys and innerloop handles the values.

Comment: Hints do not count as an answer. An answer should solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        let testData = {
            party0: 19,
            party1: 29,
            party2: 10,
            party3: 16,
            party4: 22
        };

        var keys = Object.keys(testData);
        var values = Object.values(testData)

        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < keys.length;j++){
                if(i == j) continue;
                if(i >= 0 && j > i)
                    console.log(keys[i]+":"+keys[j] +" = "+ parseInt(values[i]+values[j]));
            }
        }
```